# check preg_match results against other values?

Tags: php, preg-match

I need some help with my PHP script.
So, here is the deal.

I have a preg_match which checks for the following text  in a .txt file that changes every 30minutes or so: LYBE_TWR,LYBE_APP,LYBA_CTR,LYPG_TWR,LYPG_APP,LYTV_TWR,LYNI_APP)

It runs perfectly and gets the above strings if they are present.

But I need to do even further and check which of the seven combinations have been found because not all are present at all times.
Example:
The current text file contains LYBE_TWR, LYBE_APP, LYPG_TWR. The preg_match does its thing and I can echo the 3 values but I need this.

```
LYBE_TWR : PRESENT/NOT PRESENT
LYBE_APP: PRESENT/NOT PRESENT
LYBA_CTR PRESENT/NOT PRESENT
LYPG_TWR PRESENT/NOT RESENT 
etc.
```

So if it is found in the text file it echos present, if not it echoes not present.
The correct results would be:

```
LYBE_TWR : PRESENT
LYBE_APP: PRESENT
LYBA_CTR NOT PRESENT
LYPG_TWR PRESENT
```

If I do for example `if ($string == "LYBE_TWR") { echo 'present'; } else { echo 'not present'}` it will echo the correct value for the `LYBE_TWR` but it will say not present for the later as they are not actually the one I if-ed for.

I hope you understand as I myself am not sure anymore (rofl)

edit: here is the current code..bare in mind it is still WIP so not finished and there will be some errors http://pastebin.com/z1r4A78E
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code working on the assumption that you're interested if the string appeared in your file, not in the line. I split the strings into prefixes and suffixes, and I'm ignoring any numerical values. I didn't copy all your code, for readability's sake

```
$prefixes = array("LYBA", "LYBE", "LYPG", "LYNI", "LYTV");
$suffixes = array("TWR", "APP", "CTR");

foreach($prefixes as $prefix)
{
    foreach($suffixes as $suffix)
    {
        $results[$prefix."_".$suffix] = 0;
    }
}

if(preg_match('/^('.implode("|",$prefixes).'|)_[A-Z0-9]*_*('.implode("|",$suffixes).')/', $line, $matches))
{
    (... your code ...)
    $match_string = $matches[1]."_".$matches[2];
    $results[$match_string]++;

}

foreach($results as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
    if($value > 0)
    {
        echo " PRESENT";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " NOT PRESENT";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Though, I am still facing issues. First of all, the way you coded is that all combinations are possible. In fact, only seven are possible as I said in my initial 'post'. The possible are : LYBE_TWR,LYBE_APP,LYBA_CTR,LYPG_TWR,LYPG_APP,LYTV_TWR,LYNI_APP...Also now I get the following output for the current code; http://pastebin.com/jdXKPn9u and it continues like that for a lot longer. I hope you understand what I am trying to say. Thanks for the help